# Privilege icon alignment broken when documentation tab is selected

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The vertical alignment of the privilege icon is broken when the "documentation" tab is selected:

[image: good]

---

[image: bad]

Why still not fixed after more than 4 months?

Comment: *Why still not fixed after more than 4 months?* Because the development team has had higher priority things to work on? Does the misalignment cause the site to be unusable? No? Then chill.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan such small bugs could be easily fixed. Moreover solution is already proposed in answer. Just copy-paste from SO into SO code base.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cause of this bug is that when you select the "documentation" tab, the page loads the "docs.css" stylesheet, which adds `vertical-align: middle;` rule for `.icon` selector.

Removing the `top: 2px;` rule from selector `.rep-card .progress-bar .icon, .progress-bar.green .icon, .rep-card .progress-bar-large .icon, .progress-bar-large.green .icon` fixes this problem.

Comment: Don't you love it when people post bugs and other so users actually go out and propose a correct fix.  Its like @joelspolsky has free programmers working for him...