# Tooltip on the reputation graph on the profile page is too wide when "documentation" tab is selected

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

[image]

This is caused by `width: 300px;` rule for `.message` selector in `docs.css`.

Related: [Privilege icon alignment broken when documentation tab is selected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333409/3853934).